# How can I input the value of a formula in a cell in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
LastRowColumnA = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

Range("J2:J" & LastRowColumnA).Value = "=IF(ISBLANK(G2), "" "", MIN(G2,I2,H2+90))"
```

Cells in G, H, and I are all upcoming due dates for different categories. I am trying to have the most upcoming date revealed in Column J cells.

The formula is entered in cells in the J column correctly; however, I would like to have the columns in J have the actual value vice the formula in the cell.

To clarify:

1) As I have it now, the cells in column J have this as the cell value on the spreadsheet: `=IF(ISBLANK(G2), "", MIN(G2,I2,H2+90))`

2) I would like the cells in column J to have this as the cell value on the spreadsheet:

9/3/2020 (Example of the most upcoming date.)

Is this possible?

Comment: Select column J, 'Copy', and 'Paste Special as Values'

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I would like to have it so that if someone opens the spreadsheet, they 1) can't mess up the formula and 2) don't have to do anything (i.e. the data is ready to visualize once the spreadsheet is opened)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Range("J2:J" & LastRowColumnA).Value = Evaluate("IF(ISBLANK(G2), "" "", MIN(G2,I2,H2+90))")
```

**EDIT#1:**

Given the fact that the formula should adjust downward, try:

```
With Range("J2:J" & LastRowColumnA)
    .Value = "=IF(ISBLANK(G2), "" "", MIN(G2,I2,H2+90))"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: When I tried that, it worked only for J2. For the rest of the cells in column J, it just dragged down the same date so that all values in column J are the same date

Comment: @hawkeyesj  see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed assistance with. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
LastRowColumnA = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("J2:J" & LastRowColumnA)
    .Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(G2),"" "", MIN(G2,I2,H2+90))"
    .Formula = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
End With
```

`With Range("J2:J" & LastRowColumnA) ... End With` just tell to VBA that all of our `.<something>` will refer to our range `Range("J2:J" & LastRowColumnA)`, without writing it everytime.

`.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(G2),"" "", MIN(G2,I2,H2+90))"` set your formula to the cells in the range, like you did on your own, but it's better to specify to VBA we are setting a formula and not a value.

`.Formula = .Value` do the 'Copy&PasteByValue'

`.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"` tells Excel to display these cells as a date in day/month/year format, without adding leading zeroes to day and month fields.